# How to scan a remote repo with gitleaks

Tags: git, github, gitlab, gitleaks

I'm trying to scan a remote repo using Gitleaks (https://github.com/gitleaks/gitleaks).

I'v read the doc and a couple of examples, showing that you can use --access-token and --repo-url to scan a remote repository but now that i built the sources i get an "unknow flag".

Do you have an idea on how to do it with the new version ? or is it an alternative version of gitleaks ?

Have a nice day !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See https://github.com/gitleaks/gitleaks/issues/1035#issuecomment-1317365634 :

> *v8.0.0 removed all network activity. I.e, gitleaks does not handle cloning repos anymore. You can do something like:
>
> ```
> git clone {repo}
> cd {repo}
> gitleaks detect
> ```

`gitleaks` doesn't check remote repositories — it clones them locally. So you can clone yourself and then run `gitleaks`.